# change class of element onkeyup

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, onkeyup

I am working on `angularjs` app. It is a chat app for mobile. It has two templates

1. userlist.html
2. message.html

In `message.html` template everything works fine until when i press lets say (`<input>` tag) "enter" to type something. keyboard shows up and It doesnt slide up the view. It shows old message when keyboard is visible. So in order to slide the view up. I was thinking of binding an event on keyup of  tag and change the css class for updated view. So, I created the directive. But the problem is when i add the directive the on `<input>` tag .I am only able to access the elements of input tag. I want access the complete DOM element of template inside the directive. How to do that?

**message.html**

```
<div class="chat-sidebar-content">   element
<div class="chat-sidebar-chat chat-sidebar-panel2" id="chat-sidebar-user-1"> //I want to change class of this 

</div>

<footer class="chat-sidebar-footer form-group">
    <input class="form-control input-dark fs-mini" my-directive type="text"  placeholder="Type your message">    //added the directive here
</footer>
</div>
```

**directive.js**

```
angular.module('testApp').directive('myDirective', function() {


return function(scope, element, attr){

    console.log(element);

    element.bind("keyup", function(){

        console.log('keyup');    //this works
    });
};

});
```

Comment: Why not simply use : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup ? It has been made to this purpose.

Comment: @enguerranws How to change the css class of other element? Please explain little. I added the ng-keyup="event=$event" on input element like in plnkr , but not able to understand what to do after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what you can do :

**In the view :**

```
<input class="form-control input-dark fs-mini" ng-keyup="checkSomething()" type="text"  placeholder="Type your message">
```

**In the controller :**

```
$scope.condition;
$scope.checkSomething = function (){
    $scope.condition = true;
};
```

**In the view, again on whatever element in the same scope (controller) :**

```
<div ng-class="condition ? 'class-1' : 'class-2' " id="chat-sidebar-user-1">
```

It's just an example, if you have nothing to check, feel free to put `$scope.condition = true;` directly in the ng-keyup directive.

Comment: It's hard to get into Angular way of thinking. Just remember that the $scope(s) are the center of your app. You have to deal with $scope if you wanna update values, and so on...